# How to get Rails Heroku log backtrace from Heroku error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rubygems

I using rails 3.2.3 on Heroku Bamboo stack. I got this error last night from my logs but can't diagnose exactly where and why its occurring. How can I get the entire backtrace of the error from my heroku logs?

```
app[web.2]: !! Unexpected error while processing request: can't modify frozen array
heroku[router]: Error H13 (Connection closed without response) -> GET
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this error out? I am seeing the same thing on Heroku and having a hard time troubleshooting it.

Comment: I haven't figured it out completely yet. It occurs very sparingly, but when it does, restarting the servers always fixes it. Let me know if you get to the bottom of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, since as far as I know you cannot get the backgrace from the log file. you get what you get.

However, I can't recommend [airbrake](http://airbrakeapp.com/pages/home) enough for this type of error capturing.

Comment: Thanks CambridgeMike, we are using airbrake too and its great. However, airbrake failed to log this particular error for some reason. Any idea why it would miss this error?

Comment: Too bad this is an accepted answer. It's a good tip but does not answer the question.