# Rails regex validations throw no method error in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I have used the following regex to validate the nic number in my rails app :

```
VALID_NIC_REGEX = /\A\d{9}[V|v|x|X]\z/i
validates :nic, presence: true, allow_blank: true, format: { with: VALID_NIC_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

When I test it in my local machine, everything works fine. But after uploading to heroku, it give an error while trying to save the member with a value in the nic field. Both valid and invalid values give the error. If there's no value in the nic field, it saves the member. In the heroku log, I found this error :

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `limit' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/members_controller.rb:117:in `update'
```

So, I commented out the two validation lines and uploaded the site to Heroku. Now it works. Can some one please explain this? Thank you.

Controller update action :

```
def update
    @source = params[:source]
    @telfie = params[:telfie].to_i
    @member = Member.find(params[:id])


    @tel = Array.new

    (1..@telfie.to_i).each do |i|
         @tel << params[:tele][:"#{'tele'}#{i}"]
    end

    #params[:tele] = @tel


    if params[:commit] == 'More Numbers'
        @telfie = @telfie + 1
        render 'edit'
    else

        if params[:commit] == 'Less Numbers'
            if @telfie > 1
                @telfie = @telfie - 1
                render 'edit'
            else
                flash.now[:error] = "Can't remove all contact fields!"
                render 'edit'
            end
        else

            if @member.update_attributes(member_params)
                @member.tele = @tel
                @member.save
                flash[:success] = "Member #{@member.name} Successfully Updated!"

                if params[:commit] == 'Save Member and Add Associates'
                    redirect_to new_associate_url(memberid: @member.id, source: "memberv" )
                else
                    if @source == "database"
                        redirect_to database_path
                    else
                        redirect_to member_url(@member)
                    end
                end
            else
                render 'edit'
            end

        end

    end

end
```

Comment: please show controller update action and full backtrace

Comment: @SachinSingh I have added the update action. Can you please tell me how to get the backtrace from heroku?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640539/how-to-get-rails-heroku-log-backtrace-from-heroku-error

Comment: @Muntasim So no backtrace!

Comment: I just re added the validations and uploaded. Now its working! Any idea whats going on?

Comment: For starters, don't use `|` in character class (unless you want to match a `|` in the target string). `[V|v|x|X]` should be written: `[VvxX]`. See: [Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)